# GPRbuild: File specific compiler switches

Tags: ada, gnat

Does `GPRbuild` support a configuration option or any other way to apply special compiler switches only to special files?

That could be useful if `-gnatyXYZ` switches for strict syntax checks are used for most files in a project but some external / not project specific Ada files are not compliant with the enforced syntax checks.

Comment: There is no way to prevent the GNAT compiler from performing syntax checks. The -ganty switches perform style checking, not syntax checking.

Comment: Why are the files in the project if they are "external / not project specific"? Wouldn't it be better to put those in their own project?

Comment: @Jim Rogers: I think I mixed up syntax and style yesterday. Of course, I meant style checks.

Comment: @egilhh: I could place the files in an other project but then this separate project must be configured to build a (static) library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify both default switches for all Ada files and specific switches for individual files:

```ada
package Compiler is
   for Default_Switches ("Ada")
      use ("-O2");
   for Switches ("proc.adb")
      use ("-O0");
end Compiler;
```

GNAT's [documentation](https://docs.adacore.com/gprbuild-docs/html/gprbuild_ug/gnat_project_manager.html#tools-options-in-project-files) gives more info.