# adding -gnatp flag to a file/package in GPS

Tags: build, constraints, ada, gnat, gnat-gps

I use Ada With GPS (GNAT Programming Studio). The flag "-gnatp" when building will ignore among others constraint errors.

I know a way to add the flag to all the files, using Edit->Preferences->Build target.

Is there a way to choose when the builder will this flag, meaning setting the flag to a file or a package?

Comment: I'm not sure about GPS, but you can edit the `.gpr` file as shown in [_GPRbuild: File specific compiler switches_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55481246/230513).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Using `-gnatp` is roughly equivalent to telling the compiler not to bother checking at runtime whether you’ve made any errors (there will be some unavoidable checks, e.g. the electing expression of a case statement). This is fine if you’ve proved there can’t be any runtime errors